# I'd like to gather the data frame with two key columns in R

Tags: r

I'd like it to gather the dataframe with two key columns, one would be mean and the other variance. Here is the data frame:

```
 est1_mean  est1_var  est2_mean  est2_var  est3_mean  est3_var
1  0.2007412 0.8962381  0.2149612 0.7264134  0.2091068 0.9239417
2  0.2046424 0.7970008  0.1621528 0.9365701  0.1715687  1.014485
3  0.2013047 0.9072657    0.17906 0.9759063  0.1998138 0.7717872
4 0.07402292 0.8749833 0.09736422  1.087518  0.1167655  1.082997
```

I'd tried to use the gather function and then extract from the key column the strings that contain the "var" string and then spread the key column into two:

```
x %>%
  gather(key, value) %>%
  extract(key, c("mean", "var"), "var") %>%
  spread(var, value)
```

But I get an Error: `regex` should define 2 groups; 0 found.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `pivot_longer()`, where `.value` indicates that component of the name defines the name of the column containing the cell values.

```r
library(tidyr)

pivot_longer(df, everything(),
             names_to = c("est", ".value"),
             names_sep = "_")

# # A tibble: 12 × 3
#    est     mean   var
#    <chr>  <dbl> <dbl>
#  1 est1  0.201  0.896
#  2 est2  0.215  0.726
#  3 est3  0.209  0.924
#  4 est1  0.205  0.797
#  5 est2  0.162  0.937
#  6 est3  0.172  1.01 
#  7 est1  0.201  0.907
#  8 est2  0.179  0.976
#  9 est3  0.200  0.772
# 10 est1  0.0740 0.875
# 11 est2  0.0974 1.09 
# 12 est3  0.117  1.08
```

###### Data

```r
df <- structure(list(est1_mean = c(0.2007412, 0.2046424, 0.2013047, 0.07402292),
est1_var = c(0.8962381, 0.7970008, 0.9072657, 0.8749833),
est2_mean = c(0.2149612, 0.1621528, 0.17906, 0.09736422), 
est2_var = c(0.7264134, 0.9365701, 0.9759063, 1.087518), 
est3_mean = c(0.2091068, 0.1715687, 0.1998138, 0.1167655), 
est3_var = c(0.9239417, 1.014485, 0.7717872, 1.082997)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4"))
```